# Creating Table of contents for an existing Pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, tableofcontents

I am trying to create a table of contents for an existing pdf file and subsequently merge the table of contents page to the pdf file.Page heading and corresponding page numbers are available in a separate excel file.

I am using iText for Pdf manipulation.
All the examples i came across were related to inserting links while creating a new pdf. But in my case I want to create links for existing pages.

Any suggestion or examples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Seems to me that the Table of Contents part is a detail.  What you're really asking is how to modify an already existing PDF.  I know I'm hand waving the details, but if you can read in a PDF and write a PDF, then all you should have to do is add the TOC between those steps.  What's the problem?

Comment: My problem is how to create links to existing pages? I can add a new page to the pdf and add labels but how to point that label to a certain page number?

Comment: Ah, that's something I don't know how to do in iText, but I made a patch to make it possible in flying saucer https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/ and that uses iText so I know it must be possible.  You should check out flying-saucer.  It may be a better API for you.

Comment: @tieTYT Thanks! I ll have to read through flying-saucer to get to the point. BTW can you can share me your patch and point to me what exactly i should be using/reading in flying-saucer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. Thanks to my friend for pointing me towards an example of this in c#.

The code in java looks like :

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray("C:\\test.pdf"), null);
        Document doc = new Document(reader.getPageSize(1));
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("C:\\result.pdf"));
        Font link = FontFactory.getFont("Arial", 12, Font.UNDERLINE);
        doc.open();
        PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
        Anchor topAnchor = null;
        PdfImportedPage page = null;
        for (int i = 1; i < reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                Anchor click = new Anchor("Click to go to Target");
                click.setReference("#target");
                Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
                p1.add(click);
                doc.add(p1);
                page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                doc.newPage();
                pdfContentByte.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    Anchor target = new Anchor("My targer");
                    target.setName("target");
                    Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph();
                    p3.add(target);
                    doc.add(p3);
                }
                page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                doc.newPage();
                pdfContentByte.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a patch I made in [Flying Saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) that made it possible to click on a link and make it do something.  This was a very long time ago so I'm not sure if this will help or not, but it seems to be using iText for this.  Here's the snippet of code I think I wrote for this :P

```
private void processLink(RenderingContext c, Box box) {
    Element elem = box.getElement();
    if (elem != null) {
        NamespaceHandler handler = _sharedContext.getNamespaceHandler();
        String uri = handler.getLinkUri(elem);
        if (uri != null) {
            if (uri.length() > 1 && uri.charAt(0) == '#') {
                String anchor = uri.substring(1);
                Box target = _sharedContext.getBoxById(anchor);
                if (target != null) {
                    PdfDestination dest = createDestination(c, target);

                    if (dest != null) {
                        PdfAction action = new PdfAction();
                        if (!"".equals(handler.getAttributeValue(elem, "onclick"))) {
                            action = PdfAction.javaScript(handler.getAttributeValue(elem, "onclick"), _writer);
                        } else {
                            action.put(PdfName.S, PdfName.GOTO);
                            action.put(PdfName.D, dest);
                        }

                        com.lowagie.text.Rectangle targetArea = checkLinkArea(c, box);
                        if (targetArea == null) {
                            return;
                        }

                        targetArea.setBorder(0);
                        targetArea.setBorderWidth(0);

                        PdfAnnotation annot = new PdfAnnotation(_writer, targetArea.getLeft(), targetArea.getBottom(),
                                targetArea.getRight(), targetArea.getTop(), action);
                        annot.put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.LINK);
                        annot.setBorderStyle(new PdfBorderDictionary(0.0f, 0));
                        annot.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0.0f, 0.0f, 0));
                        _writer.addAnnotation(annot);
                    }
                }
            } else if (uri.indexOf("://") != -1) {
                PdfAction action = new PdfAction(uri);

                com.lowagie.text.Rectangle targetArea = checkLinkArea(c, box);
                if (targetArea == null) {
                    return;
                }
                PdfAnnotation annot = new PdfAnnotation(_writer, targetArea.getLeft(), targetArea.getBottom(), targetArea.getRight(),
                        targetArea.getTop(), action);
                annot.put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.LINK);

                annot.setBorderStyle(new PdfBorderDictionary(0.0f, 0));
                annot.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0.0f, 0.0f, 0));
                _writer.addAnnotation(annot);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is in the [org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextOutputDevice](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/blob/master/flying-saucer-pdf/src/main/java/org/xhtmlrenderer/pdf/ITextOutputDevice.java).

I'm not sure what context you're working in.  Is that enough information to figure out how to do this?

Comment: I am not sure how the above code would work. I ll check on this and let you know.

Comment: @RachitAgrawal see my edit.  I included a lot more context around the significant line.  Does this help?